# SyntaxHighlight - MediaWiki - Centos 8

Tags: apache-http-server, mediawiki, centos-8, mediawiki-extension

So I am using Centos 8 Stream starting from minimal install and I have built a functioning MediaWiki v1.35.4 accessible within my local network with httpd(apache).

I am trying to utilize SyntaxHighlight, but it is being treated as if I just put tags around the code. It is behaving as though I have left out all parameters. I have triple-checked and verified that my syntax is correct on the parameters and I am able to get SyntaxHighlight to work on a Mac with a locally hosted apache server.

I have tried enabling execute permissions on the pygmantize file within the SyntaxHighlight extension folder as well as enabling execute permissions on ALL files withing the extension folder and saw no difference in the result. I have also tried installing pygments outside of MediaWiki without success (which also required a python installation that did not make a difference).

I feel like there's some kind of dependency I'm missing here like maybe I need to configure Apache to recognize my python installation or something.

My wiki is currently located in the default webserver directory "/var/www/html/wiki"

Versions according to Special:Version

MediaWiki: 1.35.4

PHP: 7.4.24 (fpm-fcgi)

MySQL: 8.0.26 ICU: 65.1

Lua: 5.1.5